# Determine the Galois group of $ F(x^5) \subset F(x) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I'm rather new to Galois theory and have been given this exercise:

Suppose $ F $ is respectively equal to $ \mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{C}, \mathbb{F}_5 $ (the third one is just the 5-element field). My task is to determine the Galois group of $ F(x^5) \subset F(x) $.

I am able to prove a theorem which tells us that the order of this extension is $ 5 $. The fundamental theorem of Galois theory tells us that the Galois group of an extension is of the same order, in this case  $ 5 $, **provided the extension is Galois**. If it isn't, then the group is of smaller order.

I'm not sure how to check whether this extension is Galois - if it was, the answer would be obvious, since there's only one group of order $ 5 $.

The thing that gets me is how to see whether this extension is Galois - and, if not, what the Galois group might be.

I'd appreciate some help

Comment: If (and only if) the characteristic of $F$ is $5$ it's not separable.

Comment: If $F$ does not contain all 5th roots of unity, it is not normal.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

We have that $\;x\;$ is a root of $\;p(t)=t^5-x^5\in\Bbb F(x^5)[t]\;$ , which is a polynomial of degree five.

Over $\;\Bbb Q,\,\Bbb C\;$ the roots of $\;p(t)\;$ are $\;x^5,\,x^5w,\,x^5w^2,\,x^5w^3,\,x^5w^4\;$ , with $\;w\;$ a (primitive) root of unity of order $\;5\;$

Over $\;\Bbb F_5\;$ we have that in the extension $\;\Bbb F_5(x)/\Bbb F_5(x^5)\;$, we have

$$t^5-x^5=(t-x)^5$$

**Note:** the last decomposition is true in $\;\Bbb F_5(x)[t]\;$ !

Thus, in this last case the extension isn't even separable...

Comment: So in case where $ F = \mathbb{F}_5$, the Galois group can be of any order up to $ 4$, right? How do I determine which one it might be?

Comment: @Jytug In that case I'm not sure whether we can continue to call it "Galois Group" as, per definition, the extension cannot be Galois....but there's still an automorphisms group, (whether we call it Galois group or not), and since any such automorphism *must* map a root of that polynomial to another root, **but** there is only one such root, the autom. group is trivial, I think.